# WPF: Add ContextMenu to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu

For a second there I was proud that I finally managed to add a `ContextMenu` to a leaf in my `TreeView`, but then I realized it pops up on the wrong node.

My XAML:

```
    <TreeView 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="TvShowsTreeView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TvShows}"
        SelectedItemChanged="TvShowsTreeViewOnSelectedItemChanged">

        <!-- Season template -->
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Hide"></MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

When I run this, I get a context menu on the `TvShows`, not on the `Seasons`.

I am close, right? :) Who can help me further here?

Comment: Tried this in a Sample app, I get ContextMenu on each Season not on TvShows.

Comment: Can I borrow your PC then, I would really like to finish this :). On a more serious note, I will have a closer look tomorrow, if it works on your PC then it must be something rather silly. Thanks for this feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct XAML should be like this:

```
    <TreeView 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="TvShowsTreeView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TvShows}"
        SelectedItemChanged="TvShowsTreeViewOnSelectedItemChanged">

        <!-- TvShows template -->
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

                <!-- Seasons template -->
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Hide"></MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

The additional HierarchicalDataTemplate specifies the template for Seasons, which itself does not need to bind ItemSource because it does not contain nodes.